# Xcode white screen simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing a problem when i try to run my app it show for less that a second then switch to a white screen written on it "hello world"

this is a new project i just change the background

[image: it show this at the begging]

[image: then this in less than a second]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Evey time i want to run my app it shows the hello world page

Comment: Have you by any chance modified the LaunchScreen.storyboard by adding a purple background only instead of modifying the Main.storyboard as you should have done?

Comment: I wasted time for the same issue and found a problem (!!!). Issue appeared after I updated my XCode to v.11.1. So, сreated a new project and on popup "Choose options for your new project" change value of "User Interface" from "SwiftUI" to "Storyboard". Once you will choose "Storyboard" you wil get already configured Main.Storyboard with a viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS apps use a `Launch Screen` whilst loading the app, then they will load the default view controller/storyboard.

In your case here, your launch screen has a purple background and is only shown for a short time until the app initializes and shows it's first screen.

The "Hello world" page is your initial view controller of your app. You either need to modify this UIViewController or change the starting view controller to another one.

Comment: i waited for more than 5 min and nothing chaged

Comment: it wont change? why would it? from a brand new project xcode gives you a view controller for free, with hello world on it. if you haven't changed that to something else then it wont change??

Comment: "Your app" IS the screen with hello world on it. the purple screen is like a screensaver or loading screen only.

Comment: this what i thought , but is there any option to change it ?

Comment: @omaralomran yes you change the code or design of the first view controller in your Main.storyboard file..

Comment: When you created your new project have you selected to use SwiftUI or storyboards? do you have a main.storyboard file in your app? if so this is where your first view controller with Hello world is and that is where you change it

Comment: Thank you so much, this my first time in a while in using the xcode the problem is i did not change it to storyboard